# Devemos incentivar código em português?

Tags: debate

Ok, temos um site de perguntas e respostas em português. Isso é ótimo, pois falando nossa língua nativa podemos nos sentir mais à vontade e, muitas vezes, dar respostas mais sucintas.

Mas o fato é que estamos todos acostumados a um mundo em que o núcleo da programação pertence ao inglês. Aliás, nem todas as linguagens possuem suporte para caracteres acentuados como identificadores válidos, por exemplo -- e não sei sobre todos, mas eu me sinto estranho escrevendo código em português sem acento.

Outro ponto é que não se traduz API nem palavras-chave; e outras pessoas podem se sentir estranhas escrevendo parcialmente em inglês e parcialmente em português. (Eu me sinto)

Minha pergunta, no final, é: Enquanto o conteúdo **explicativo** de nossas respostas é em português, o conteúdo de **código** também deve ser? Devemos incentivar o código em português, em inglês, ou deixar à escolha do usuário?

Comment: +1 por uma pergunta interessante e que é dificil defenir ou responder de maneira absolutista. Existem já duas perguntas relacionadas, que devem ser referidas [(1)](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165/traducao-de-vocabulario-tecnico-em-ingles), [(2)](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/deveremos-de-manter-algum-standard-linguistico-ou-nao).

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado pelas referências, mas vale notar aqui que eu não sou a favor de uma distinção entre dialetos de português (como citado em uma das referências); apenas saber se devemos usar português no código, independente do dialeto.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não necessariamente. Acho que cada um pode fazer como achar melhor, principalmente se tiver contexto adequado para um caso ou outro, mas na maioria dos casos, tanto faz.

Se tiver comentários importantes no código, seria legal, mas não obrigatório, traduzi-los.

Símbolos próprios podem ser usados em inglês mesmo, mas é legal usar em português também.

Acho que nem preciso dizer que não pode traduzir o que não é traduzível. Não vamos fazer como nos anos 80 onde a lei de [reserva de mercado de informática](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_Nacional_de_Inform%C3%A1tica) que durou entre 1977 e 1992 atrasou todo nosso desenvolvimento e incentivava existir produtos como o Dialog que era um clone do [dBase](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBASE) com comandos em português!!!

Não precisamos criar regras que não solucionam problemas. Este site foi criado para resolver o problema da falta conteúdo bom, organizado, relevante em português e também que algumas pessoas não podiam participar do site original em inglês por não conseguirem trocar informações em inglês confortavelmente. Não foi criado como ode ao português. Todos entendemos um pouco de inglês. Não há necessidade de exageros. Como os professores famosos da TV costumam dizer, o importante é se comunicar adequadamente. Não somos informais ao ponto de permitir qualquer desorganização, mas também não estamos escrevendo teses aqui.

Comment: Gostei, principalmente da parte dos comentários. Acho que seria o caso mais adequado -- não banalizando os outros. Acho que isso deve ser mais flexível, no final...

Comment: Concordo. Nunca me conformei que a Microsoft traduziu as fórmulas do Excel. Aí ficamos com aberrações como `NÚM.CARACT()` para `LENGTH`.

Comment: @bfavaretto bem lembrado :) Quem consegue usar Excel se vira com length, quem não se vira, não consegue fazer outras coisas no Excel.

Comment: Eu queria poder votar positivamente duas vezes. Uma pela qualidade da resposta, a outra pela menção à terrível reserva de mercado.