# Como tratar de sugestões de edição que alteram código?

Tags: debate, edição

Ontem me deparei com [**uma sugestão de edição**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2541) que se propunha a alterar código de uma resposta. A edição está correta e o código original pré-edição não funcionava como deveria. Mas optei por rejeitar a sugestão propondo que fosse feito um comentário pedindo que o próprio autor fizesse a mudança (no fim foi aprovada por ele).

Meu pensamento é que edição de respostas devem se limitar a alterações editoriais (pontuação, ortografia, highlight, formatação, etc) e nunca alterar o que está sendo dito ou o sentido da resposta. Isso se aplica também a respostas que estejam claramente erradas.

Qual é a atitude correta ao se deparar com uma sugestão de edição nos seguintes casos?

- **Corrige um erro do código que foi causado por um mero erro de digitação ou por escrever rapidamente sem testar** (sem mudar a forma como o código funciona nem nenhuma correção além do que já foi dito).
- **Altera o código para tratar de um caso que não foi previsto pelo autor da resposta** (algum *edge case* ou bug em potencial de que a resposta não tratava)
- **Formatação de espaços e quebras de linha** (apenas estilo)
- **Tradução de comentários ou identificadores** (código original foi escrito em inglês (ou copiado de algum lugar) e alguém traduziu)

Answer (score 15):

Concordo com quase tudo que o [bfavaretto falou na resposta dele](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/750/12).

Respostas aqui não são feitas com o intuito de irem direto pra produção, e nem deviam ser. Erros podem acontecer por qualquer desatenção -- como é o caso da edição citada -- e acredito que a edição (assim como o comentário) é uma boa forma de lidar com isso, desde que você tenha experiência e consciência do que está fazendo.

Dito isso, o mesmo cuidado vale para o **revisor**. Ninguém é obrigado a dar seu parecer sobre todas as sugestões de edição que encontrar, e nem vai ser penalizado por isso. Se você viu uma edição de código e não está familiarizado com a linguagem/ambiente/framework/problema o suficiente para conseguir fazer um julgamento válido, só passar pro próximo. Deixe que alguém com mais experiência no assuno decida se aquela edição é válida. Parte da magia do trabalho colaborativo que move o site é que ninguém é unicamente responsável por nada.

Por outro lado, se você gostaria de fazer uma mudança trivial -- um erro de digitação, gramática, etc. mesmo no código fonte -- não há motivo pra deixar o comentário antes. Fazer a edição o mais rápido possível melhora a qualidade do site. O habito de deixar um comentário **antes** de editar é benéfico quando se pede melhorias significativas no conteúdo, onde o próprio autor tem a chance de aprender algo novo sobre o assunto ou o SOPT. Para coisas menores, edite à vontade.

Answer (score 14):

No geral eu concordo com você. Primeiro notificaria o autor em um comentário. Caso não haja retorno dentro de um tempo razoável (1 dia?), aí sim eu faria o ajuste no código, **contanto que eu tenha certeza de que estou fazendo uma alteração tecnicamente correta.**

Sobre cada caso que você citou:

> Corrige um erro do código que foi causado por um mero erro de digitação ou por escrever rapidamente sem testar (sem mudar a forma como o código funciona nem nenhuma correção além do que já foi dito).

Vale o que eu disse acima.

> Altera o código para tratar de um caso que não foi previsto pelo autor da resposta (algum edge case ou bug em potencial de que a resposta não tratava)

Depende da complexidade da alteração. Pode ser o caso de adicionar uma nova resposta, citando a original.

> Formatação de espaços e quebras de linha (apenas estilo)

Esse tipo de alteração dá para fazer sem nem consultar o autor, se a formatação estiver confusa. Se for para trocar o estilo porque o autor usou um que você não gosta, não altere.

> Tradução de comentários ou identificadores (código original foi escrito em inglês (ou copiado de algum lugar) e alguém traduziu)

Eu traduziria comentários sem consultar o autor, mas não tenho certeza se traduziria os identificadores.

Um caso que você não mencionou, mas que considero válido editar em respostas: acrescentar um exemplo ou link para referência.

Comment: Muito boa essa abordagem de notificar e esperar o autor da resposta. Eu gostaria que fizessem isso se fosse comigo. Por outro lado, caso eu não tivesse tempo, não ligaria de alguém corrigir a resposta. É importante o bom senso.

Answer (score 12):

Sou favorável em poucas situações:

- **Formatação**. Mesmo assim, com cuidado para não interferir na intenção do autor. Já vi alterações assim no SO que prejudicava o que estava tentando mostrar. É mais raro, mas essas situações existem.
- Com **autorização do autor**. Mas neste caso provavelmente o autor mesmo faz a edição.
- Erro que não tenha dúvida que seja de **digitação**. Vale o mesmo do primeiro item. Cuidado para não mexer em algum erro proposital e principalmente em casos que você não sabia que podia usar assim.

Ressalto ainda:

- Traduções só podem ser feitas com autorização do autor.
- Qualquer outro tipo de melhoria não citado, mesmo que seja obviamente o melhor para o código, não deve ser feita. **Respeite a intenção do autor**. Mesmo que ele esteja errado. Você pode notificá-lo mas não pode sair mexendo no que não é seu. Sugira a alteração e faça-a se o autor autorizar.
- Tem um **jeito melhor de fazer** o que o autor da resposta propôs? **Faça a sua resposta** e cite a dele. Você aprende, contribui, ganha reputação, ajuda a todos, inclusive ao autor da resposta que não estava tão boa. Acha radical? Eu não acho. Se você sabe fazer melhor, mostre e receba o crédito. Dê o crédito para a ideia original quando couber. Ainda acha radical? Então apenas sugira ao autor melhorar. Mas ele pode não querer não alterar e não quer que você altere. O melhor que você pode fazer para a comunidade é prover sua própria resposta melhorada.

Se for em pergunta, a chance de mexer deve ser mais restrita ainda. Quase limitada a formatação. Mesmo assim, com cuidado para não estragar alguma coisa. Há casos que melhorar o código significa resolver o problema silenciosamente. Aí não há quem ache o problema.

Lembrando sempre que esta é minha opinião. Qualquer um pode pensar diferente.

E não vou recriminar você por votar contra uma resposta errada ;)

Comment: Um exemplo que não é código mas que foi colocada palavras na boca de outra pessoa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/2515/revisions. Pode estar certo, pode ser que o bfavaretto tenha gostado, mas foi colocado conteúdo, talvez de um jeito que ele não goste, na resposta dele. Essa pode ter sido certa, mas pode acontecer de acidentalmente denegrir a imagem do autor para quem não olha a revisão. Principalmente em alguém que não visita o site regularmente. Não estou criticando esse caso específico, apenas dando um exemplo de que isso é perigoso.

Comment: Exatamente. Essa foi sim certa, mas escrita de uma maneira um pouco diferente da que eu usaria. Concordo que há riscos nesses tipo de atitude.

Answer (score 5):

Em dois pontos eu sou a favor da alteração do código-fonte:

- **Alterar o código para tratar de um caso que não foi previsto pelo autor**
- **Tradução de comentários ou identificadores***

No primeiro caso, eu sou a favor, pois acho que tem muito mais valia corrigir na resposta, do que dar outra resposta para informar que o usuário estava errado. Acaba acrescentando mais corrigir o código, do que deixar duas respostas separadas que acabam falando a mesma coisa.

Já no segundo caso eu coloquei um asterisco, pois eu acho que **identificadores** devem permanecer os mesmos, já que eu parto do preceito que códigos em inglês devem ser aceitos,no entanto, acho que comentários serem traduzidos é uma prática interessante, já que eles tem o intuito de explicar uma parte de código, o que segue, mais ou menos, [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/731/1333).

Os outros dois pontos, eu já não sou a favor, já que ele não tem intuito nenhum de melhorar o código, no caso da "corrige um erro do código...", essa é uma edição minoritária que pode ser feito por usuários que não ganham pontos por essa edição, como é visto nos comentários [dessa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/659/onde-esta-o-conjunto-de-regras).
Já o ponto de "formatação de espaços e quebras de linha" é um ponto extremamente subjetivo, a velha [história de abrir chaves na mesma linha ou na linha de baixo](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line), sendo que não existe uma forma correta, mas sim a característica que cada desenvolvedor se sente mais confortável.