# Sobre edições de conteúdo em respostas

Tags: debate, edição, respostas

Eu procurei aqui no meta alguma questão sobre isso, mas não achei. Se for duplicado, por favor sinalizem e me perdoem.

Já recebi umas três ou quatro análises sobre edições em respostas que vão além de correções ortográficas ou adição de *syntax highlight* e coisas do tipo, pois alteram o conteúdo da resposta. O último exemplo que eu recebi foi [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/como-usar-varios-comandos-sql-no-caso-delete-no-oracle-em-uma-linha-so-no-c/4310#4310).

Sei que a intenção é ajudar, mas particularmente eu fico um pouco desconfortável com edições desse tipo não apenas porque informações equivocadas podem prejudicar a reputação do respondente, mas  porque acho que é mais educado (e até mesmo mais ético) fazer uma sugestão em um comentário do que diretamente editar a resposta de outra pessoa.

Eu já rejeitei propostas de edição algumas vezes comentando que achava mais apropriado fazer um comentário, mas nesse exemplo que eu citei eu aprovei a edição porque o que foi adicionado foi um código de exemplo que dificilmente caberia em um comentário. Se por um lado eu ainda ache que edições de resposta são delicadas, faz parte também da intenção da comunidade ter conteúdo decente que seja resultado de trabalho coletivo.

Como vocês procedem nesses casos (ou, o que recomendam)?

Answer (score 5):

Não é exatamente duplicada, mas já discutimos sobre isso em alguns lugares.

De fato, edições não devem alterar o conteúdo, só a forma. Especialmente mexer em código.

Não podemos aceitar edições que colocam palavras na boca de outras pessoas. Elas devem ser rejeitadas.

Em [Como tratar de sugestões de edição que alteram código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/749/como-tratar-de-sugestoes-de-edicao-que-alteram-codigo) falo com mais detalhes.

Você está procedendo corretamente.

Se não cabe um comentário, cabe uma resposta. A pessoa pode dizer "a resposta do fulano é boa, mas falou isso aqui" e fica bom para todo mundo, o autor da resposta original, o autor da nova resposta, o autor da pergunta e toda a comunidade. Fora que as pessoas que podem lidar com edições, não teriam mais essa tarefa.

O trabalho pode ser coletivo mesmo em respostas diferentes. Se o autor da resposta quisesse que todo mundo mexesse na resposta dele, ele teria marcado como CW.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pelo link da outra questão (foi mals; juro que não encontrei nas buscas, mas sabia que isso era suficientemente importante pra já ter sido discutido).