# Aprovação de edição da resposta pelo Autor

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-nãorepro, edição

**Relacionado**: [Como tratar de sugestões de edição que alteram código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/749/como-tratar-de-sugest%C3%B5es-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-alteram-c%C3%B3digo)

Hoje me deparei com um caso de uma [edição numa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15804) de minha autoria.

A edição da pergunta realmente faz sentido, tanto que corrigi o problema com base num comentário. **Porém se não fosse o comentário eu não iria corrigir o problema**, pois a edição foi prontamente rejeitada.

Não quero entrar ao mérito se a reprovação foi devida ou não. Lembro que no https://dba.stackexchange.com/ tive uma resposta editada e eu fui notificado para analisar a edição.

Acredito que o processo de edição de respostas lá seja mais eficiente, pois o próprio autor é notificado para a avaliação. É possível implementar algo parecido aqui no SO pt ?

Comment: Aqui como em qualquer outro site da SE funciona do mesmo jeito, o AP é notificado e a edição entra na fila de análises, simultaneamente. Se os analisadores forem mais rápidos que você eles analisarão na sua frente. Sei que você não perguntou, mas em minha opinião os analisadores agiram corretamente ao rejeitar a edição.

Comment: Fogo sou sempre eu a aparecer ali :P

Comment: @Math não sabia que entrava simultaneamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui como em qualquer outro site da SE funciona do mesmo jeito: quando um usuário que não tem o privilégio de editar publicações faz uma edição ela vira na verdade uma sugestão de edição, e não é aplicada automaticamente. Essa sugestão vai para a fila de análises para as pessoas que têm o privilégio de analisar, e ao mesmo tempo uma notificação é enviada para o autor da publicação avisando que existe uma sugestão de edição em uma publicação sua. O autor da publicação, por mais que não tenha a reputação necessária para analisar a fila de edições sugeridas passa a ter o direito de analisar a sugestão (por ser o autor). Se ele demorar para fazer a análise outros usuários acabarão fazendo.

A grande diferença dos usuários que não são os autores da publicação para o autor, é que o autor pode por si só decidir se a sugestão vai ser aprovada ou rejeitada, enquanto a aprovação pelos demais usuários precisa de dois votos aprovando ou dois rejeitando para concluir a análise.